# Double click event to fill textbox in form

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use double-click event of worksheet to populate a textbox in a form with value from a specific column in the double-clicked row.

e.g.

I have four columns

```
ID Name Age Gender
1  A     24  M
2  B     26  F
3  C     22  F
4  D     30  M
```

When I double-click on any cell in the column `Name`, a form with a textbox will pop up with the textbox filled with the value from the column `Gender` in the row which was double-clicked. SO when I double-click on "B" in column Name a form should pop up with textbox value "F".

this is my code so far

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, CANCEL As Boolean)
    CANCEL = True
    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Update.Show
        With Update.TextBox1.value = ?????
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You're looking for `Target.Value` for your "?????", but you either need that line *before* you show the UserForm or have the form open modeless. Also see [Best Practices in the User Forms documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5351/user-forms/19036/best-practices#t=201609221422259238642).

Comment: It didnt work and aslo wont target.value will fill the textbox with double clicked cell value. I want it to fill the value from a specific column on the double clicked  cell row

Comment: Sorry, That would be `Target.Offset(0, x).Value` where `x` is the number of columns to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Using a form called `frm_Update` with three appropriately named text box controls.
This will take the value from the `Target` row, columns 2, 3 and 4 and place the values in the textboxes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim oForm As frm_Update

    If Target.Column = 2 Then
        Set oForm = New frm_Update

        Cancel = True
        With oForm
            .txtName = Cells(Target.Row, 2)
            .txtAge = Cells(Target.Row, 3)
            .txtGender = Cells(Target.Row, 4)
            .Show
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

@Comintern - I'm going to have a good read of that link.  All stuff I really should put into practice.

Answer (score 0):

I used the double click event to open the form & form activate event to fetch the value from the column in the active cell row

so its basically

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, CANCEL As Boolean)
    CANCEL = True
    If Target.Column = 2 Then Exit Sub
    Update.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim r As Long

    r = ActiveCell.Row

    Me.TextBox1.value = Cells(r, 4).value
```