# Double click event in the excel sheet column to fill all textboxes of a Userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use double-click event of worksheet to populate a all textboxes in a userform with value when click on a specific column in the double-clicked row.

> Eg: I have 6 columns

```html
ID Project  Approval  tool  status  feedback 
1   A1         yes    123   ongoing  good   
2   B2         no     456   stop     bad
```

When I double-click on any cell in the column ID, userform with a textbox will pop up with the textbox filled with the value from the all columns (Project, Aprroval, tool, Status, Feedback) the row which was double-clicked. SO, when I double-click on "1" in column ID a userform should pop up with textbox value "A1", "yes", "123", "ongoing", "good".

this is my code so far i am trying for the double click Event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, CANCEL As Boolean)
Dim UserForm2 As frm_Update

    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Set UserForm2 = New frm_Update

        CANCEL = True
        With UserForm2

            Dim wks As Worksheet
            Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            wks.Activate
            .txtProject = Cells(Target.Row, 2)
            .txtapproval = Cells(Target.Row, 3)
            .txttool = Cells(Target.Row, 4)
            .txtstatus = Cells(Target.Row, 5)
            .txtfeedback = Cells(Target.Row, 6)

            Me.Show
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

i used this [Double click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641475/double-click-event-to-fill-textbox-in-form) as a reference to my Problem but I am not able to solve the Problem. My userform is not opening when i run the Code.

Comment: What is the Me good for if you want to show the userform. Me refers to the sheet and not the the userform. It should not even compile as SHow is not a method of the sheet,

Comment: Also, you don't need to activate your sheet. You already have a binding to your sheet. So, delete `wks.Activate` and change your cell calls to: **`.txtProject = wks.Cells(Target.Row, 2)`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Me` in the event routine of a sheet refers to the *worksheet*, not to the *form*. As a worksheet has not `Show`-method, you should get a runtime error.
Simple change the line to `.Show` should display the form.

To avoid such errors, always put `Option explicit` at the top of all modules. If you do, you would get a compiler error *Method or data member not found*

Comment: And it is always a good idea to do a _Debug/Compile_ then the compiler had reported a missing method.

Comment: I tried now with all changes but I am getting error "User-defined type not defined" in this line:  Dim UserForm2 As frm_Update

Comment: That means you do not have a userform `frm_Update`

Comment: Actually my Userform Name is 'Userform2'. Shall I replace as frm_Userform2

Comment: No! If the name is `Userform2` then you have to write `Dim frm_Update As UserForm2` and later `Set frm_Update = New UserForm2`. I hope you know by then what to do with `With UserForm2`. I'd also suggest to read [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/)

Comment: Perfect!! it worked exactly, may i know is it possible to give a range for the double click Event i.e. when double clicked on any of the column cells between " A to C " the userform fill the textboxes.

Comment: I'd say _Yes_ but this seems to be a new question.

Comment: Yes,  I am trying with this Code :  Set fvalue = wks.Range("A:C").Find(What:=Me.txtID.Value, Me.txtproject.Value, Me.txtApproval.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)